# Inconsistent behavior of setspace package in ctable doinside

Tags: tables, line-spacing, incompatibility, setspace, ctable

This is odd:

```
\ctable[
doinside=\singlespacing,
%doinside=\setstretch{1}
]
{lp{5cm}}
{}
{\FL
Blubb & Blobb simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum
    has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s. \ML
\LL
}
```

`\singlespacing` in `doinside` gives various Errors. `\doublespacing`, `\onehalfspacing` works, as does `\setstretch{x}`. Could this be a bug? If so, where to report it? And do I get the same linespacing with `\setstretch{1}` as with `\singlespacing`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contrary to `\doublespacing` and `\onehalfspacing`, the `\singlespacing` command also adds a *"Correction for coming into singlespace"* (comment in `setspace.sty`), namely `\vskip\baselineskip`, and this results in `\ctable` producing an error. So either change the definition of `\singlespacing` or preferably use `\setstretch{1}` inside a `ctable`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{setspace}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\singlespacing}{%
  \setstretch{\setspace@singlespace}%
%  \vskip\baselineskip% REMOVED
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{ctable}

\begin{document}

\ctable[
doinside=\singlespacing,
%doinside=\setstretch{1}
]
{lp{5cm}}
{}
{\FL
Blubb & Blobb simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum
    has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s. \ML
\LL
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. The inner workings of Tex will always remain a mystery to me, but hooray for people like you who can explain us what's going on. ;)